# Bag of Words Classification Using KNN

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, knn

I have computed bag of words models for training and testing images. I have 260 bow vectors(100x1) for training images and 282 bow vectors (100x1) for testing images. I would like to classify the test images by using knn algorithm. However, I don't know how to use those bow vectors.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement KNN?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to use KNN in your decision process.

To able to use KNN, you need to calculate a distance between two vectors. You can use the norm to calculate distance. Fortunately, MATLAB is doing this for us if you have Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox.

Let X be a vector and the each row of it is your 1x100 BOW vectors(transpose of them). and y be a vector that assign the class of each BOW vector. For instance, if you want to classify the images whether they includes bicycle or not, your y must contain binary(if bicycle is presented in image : 1 or Otherwise: 0) information about each histogram.

```
x = [ - ---- -- - -- -  first histogram;         y = [1;
      - - - ---- -- --  second histogram;             0;
       - ---- - ------  third histogram]              1]

mdl = fitcknn(X,y); %this will be your model.
```

Actually, I don't know whether it will work or not with BOW, because I always use SVM with it. So, good luck and please inform us if it worked or not.

Comment: KNN is a valid machine learning approach that works surprisingly well in many case. IMHO it would be wise to try the simpler KNN before jumping into SVM, especially that  KNN is trivial to implement

Comment: Yes, you are right. I searched a bit after this question is posted, so I guess, I need to edit my answer; however, my assumption was there would be some misunderstanding in Bag of Words implementation, because BOW uses KNN before training stage and question is not so clear.